# How can I play videos in Stream (Azure Media player) of a page loaded with CEFSharp in WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, chromium-embedded

I am creating a web browser with **CefSharp** which has to navigate in the Microsoft Stream page.
When loading the same page in another browser such as *Chrome or Edge*, it plays well, but I have an error when loading the video.

I hope someone knows both a configuration for **Cef** or a **Nuget package** for *WPF* with which to play the videos.

Comment: The formats used are probably proprietary see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#multimedia-audiovideo

Comment: Thank you, it is a great clue to continue researching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @amaitland 's opinion in comment.

CefSharp is based on Chromium which only support limit audio and video formats.

I use the CefSharp sample from: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

I can play a mp3 audio with Azure Media Player which means that AMP can work in Cef/Chromium. But if I play a mp4 file, I will get error.

You may build your own Chromium as: https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13515&start=40